# ListViewItem IsSelected TwoWay Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've created a "DarkMode" theme for my application but the `IsSelected` binding for the `ListViewItem` is not working. When I select an item/items they highlight as expected (I.e. the MultiTriggers are applying the correct highlight colour), so the ListView obviously thinks `IsSelected == True`. But the Setter is never called so the property in my model is never updated.

If I remove the `x:Key="RemoteComputerItem"` style it works fine (I.e. the Setter is called and my model is updated). Removing all of the triggers in that style make no difference (I obviously don't see the items being highlighted, but the Setter is still not called). So that only leaves the following:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Border x:Name="Bd">
        <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I believe the problem lies within the control template above, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Am I missing something? or do I need to use something else in place of the `GridViewRowPresenter`?

My XAML is below. I haven't included the C# as I think the problem lies here and don't want to make the question too long, but I'm happy to add it if needed.

**View:**

```
<ListView x:Name="ADComputers" Margin="0" Padding="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Computers, ElementName=ADTree, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource RemoteComputerItem}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RemoteComputerItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusText}" Value="Offline">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="20">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Computer Name" util:SortOrderGlyph.IsSorted="False" util:SortOrderGlyph.SortDirection="True">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SortCol">
                                    <cal:Parameter Value="Name" />
                                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}}" />
                                </cal:ActionMessage>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <!-- More columns like above, removed to shorten -->

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**Separate Resource Dictionary for DarkMode theme:**

```
<Style x:Key="RemoteComputerItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd">
                    <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource SelectedBackgroundColor}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is some more code to give you the full picture of the bindings, but as I mentioned above the bindings work perfectly when I remove the control template for the ListViewItem.

As you can see above, the ListView is bound to `SelectedItem.Computers` of the element `ADTree`. Here is the XAML for `ADTree`:

```
<TreeView Margin="0, -1, 0, 0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ADTree" ItemsSource="{Binding ADRoot.Children}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:OUModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The TreeView is bound to `ADRoot.Children`:

```
class ADTreeViewModel : OUModel
{
    public OUModel ADRoot { get; set; } = new OUModel(null, false);
}

class OUModel : PropertyChangedBase, ITreeViewItemViewModel
{
    // TreeView is bound to this property, which holds a collection of more OUModel objects
    public BindableCollection<ITreeViewItemViewModel> Children { get; set; } = new BindableCollection<ITreeViewItemViewModel>();

    // The ListView's ItemSource is bound to ADTree.SelectedItem.Computers which is this property
    public List<RemoteComputer> Computers
    {
        get { return computers; }
        set { computers = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(); } 
    }

// PropertyChangedBase is from Caliburn.Micro
class RemoteComputer : PropertyChangedBase
{

    // All other properties in this class are being displayed correctly in the ListView, so the DataContext is correct E.g.:
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool isSelected = false;

    // The ListViewItem's IsSelected property is bound to this
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(); // Caliburn.Micro gets the property name itself

            // I've also tried adding the following
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Parent.Children);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Live Property Explorer for an item which IS selected:

[image: Live Property Explorer]

Comment: <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" /> Is wrong. Value can be True or False and not Binding. If you are using Behavior: then try {Binding DataContext.IsSelected}

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried `{Binding DataContext.IsSelected}` and `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.IsSelected}` but neither of them made any difference.

Comment: Do you see Binding Error in Output window? Try to work your way from that Info. Also at times Setters dont fire unless you have set the same property in the element once.

Comment: What @Prateek says in their first comment is wrong. The Value of a Style Setter can of course be a Binding. `<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>` is a valid expression, provided that there is an IsSelected property in the current DataContext of the ListViewItem.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava There are no binding errors in the output window. I've used the Live Property Viewer to select the DataContext of the ListViewItem to watch if the IsSelected property is updated (I am refreshing the Live Property window after selecting the item), I'm not just relying on a break point in the setter.

Comment: I've solved the problem, but don't understand why it didn't work. It appears that nothing in the style I applied directly in the ListView itself works (which includes the IsSelected property). But that style is `BasedOn="{StaticResource RemoteComputerItem}"` so I don't understand why it doesn't apply. The XAML I'm talking about is in the code block titled 'View' in my question. If I move the IsSelected property into the separate resource dictionary for my theme, it works. Any ideas?